# Handling 'Pear Mail to text/SMS' truncated messages

Tags: php, email, sms, pear

I am using the PEAR mail library to process emails on my PHP site with great success but tonight I am researching a known issue in hopes for a resolution.

I know that by sending email to cell numbers like 3334445555@vtext.com will submit my message as a text message to the recipients phone.

My issue with this is that the message truncates.
The most obvious answer is to keep my messages short.

Should I strlen() the message, and loop the mail submission until the entire message has been processed or is there a switch within pear that I am un aware of?

Thanks in advance for any responses.

-Patrick (Drinking and typing aren't working well together this evening.)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to do the splitting manually as you suggested.

There is no "switch" in the library that does this for you.